# Can SystemC diplay circuits as a drawing?

Tags: vhdl, systemc

I need to design some digital circuits , but it kills me drawing them by hand. I've searched a easier way to do them, and found VHDL and what's more interesting SystemC. The last one is pretty nice and easy to understand but i need to be able to print the results in a Visual Representation of the circuit.

Is the SystemC able to print the circuit as a Drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemC is a language and not a tool. You have to find a environment which provides tools for SystemC such as this one : http://www.mirabilisdesign.com/Pages/Product/mdi_SC.htm

But you also have the free ISE form Xilinx for VHDL : http://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.htm
These are great and reliable tools.

Comment: I thought for using SystemC i only have to download the SystemC.h header file and include it. I was thinking if there was a function for generating a graphical output. However an module is fine too. Thank you, i'll give it a try immediately.

Comment: ISE is a complete software suite to make things from designing your circuits to simulate them ant push them into specific hardware. You may feel lost in the software at the beginning, but take time to learn it with the documentation and you will not be disappointed !

Comment: Yes, confusing is the right word for this. I will try the ISE but VHDL language seems to be confusing for now. From what i've seen is a pretty interesting piece of software with abilities far more advanced than i need.Also i will try some SystemC environments since i have some c++ background, maybe a tool which combines both SystemC and VHDL. Thank you for a great hint, i will continue the research.

Comment: Dont hesitate to post a new comment once you have found what are looking for !

Answer (score 1):

No, SystemC is only a C++ library, but [GBL Design Studio](http://www.gbresearch.com/gbl/Default.aspx) additionally has a graphical designer and tracer, all in one package.